NextJS/Tailwind Shared Hero Component and different bg images for size
I am trying to make a shared hero component that changes image based on screen size (it is part of a challenge). I am implementing it as a background image but can't seem to get it to work.
I was able to statically set the image bg for each breakpoint, but not when I try to make it a shared component.
Here is what I have:
hero.jsx

const hero = ({
  hero_desktop,
  hero_tablet,
  hero_mobile
}) => {
return (
  <section>
    <div className={`bg-${hero_mobile} md:bg-${hero_tablet} lg:bg-${hero_desktop} 
                     h-[500px] bg-cover bg-center bg-no-repeat w-full rounded-lg`}>
      {
       ...
      }
    </div>
  </section>
)
}

parent component:
page.jsx
const Subscribe = () => {
...
return (
  <div className='w-full'>
    <SharedHero 
      hero_desktop={planhero_desktop}
      hero_tablet={planhero_tablet}
      hero_mobile={planhero_mobile}    
/>
  </div> 
)
}

tailwind config:
...
backgroundImage: {
  planhero_mobile: "url('/assets/plan/mobile/hero.jpg')",
planhero_tablet: "url('/assets/plan/tablet/hero.jpg')",
planhero_desktop: "url('/assets/plan/desktop/hero.jpg')",
}


This should resolve the issue and allow your shared hero component to work correctly across different screen sizes.
const Hero = ({ hero_desktop, hero_tablet, hero_mobile }) => {
  return (
    <section>
      <div
        className={`h-[500px] bg-cover bg-center bg-no-repeat w-full rounded-lg ${
          hero_mobile ? `bg-[url(${hero_mobile})]` : ''
        } md:${hero_tablet ? `bg-[url(${hero_tablet})]` : ''} lg:${
          hero_desktop ? `bg-[url(${hero_desktop})]` : ''
        }`}
      >
        ...
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Hero;


